# Can I increase int i by more than one using the i++ syntax?

Tags: c++, c

int fkt(int &i)
    {
      return i++;
    }

```
int main()
{
  int i = 5;
  printf("%d ", fkt(i));
  printf("%d ", fkt(i));
  printf("%d ", fkt(i));
}
```

prints '5 6 7 '. Say I want to print '5 7 9 ' like this, is it possible to do it in a similar way without a temporary variable in fkt()? (A temporary variable would marginally decrease efficiency, right?) I.e., something like

```
return i+=2
```

or

```
return i, i+=2;
```

which both first increases i and then return it, what is not what I need.

Thanks

EDIT: The main reason, I do it in a function and not outside is because fkt will be a function pointer. The original function will do something else with i. I just feel that using {int temp = i; i+=2; return temp;} does not seem as nice as {return i++;}.

I don't care about printf, this is just for illustration of the use of the result.

EDIT2: Wow, that appears to be more of a chat here than a traditional board :) Thanks for all the answers. My fkt is actually this. Depending on some condition, I will define get_it as either get_it_1, get_it_2, or get_it_4:

```
unsigned int (*get_it)(char*&);

unsigned int get_it_1(char* &s)
  {return *((unsigned char*) s++);}
unsigned int get_it_2(char* &s)
  {unsigned int tmp = *((unsigned short int*) s); s += 2; return tmp;}
unsigned int get_it_4(char* &s)
  {unsigned int tmp = *((unsigned int*) s); s += 4; return tmp;}
```

For get_it_1, it is so simple... I'll try to give more background in the future...

Comment: Ignore those efficiency considerations and use a solution that works.

Comment: I just want to make sure you realize that printf is thousands of times slower than i+=2.

Comment: Have you seen the asm code for your example? There is no temporary variable in "i+=2" expression. The "2" can be passed through the registry, or it may be encoded inside the machine command directly. Modern c++ compilers will compile "i+=2" with absolutely no overhead.

Comment: SadSido is right...i+=2; return i; would be the same. if you think about it, i++ is really just a convenient way of saying i+=1, which is a convenient way of saying i=i+1. (Kind of funny how we programmers have come up with convenient ways to make our convenient ways more convenient) 

You wouldn't have any overhead because assembly instructions already have an "add immediate" option for addition with integers. No extra registers required!

Comment: @SadSido: The +=2 example doesn't work though - he wants post increment by two, that gives pre-increment by 2.

Comment: @Ramonster: heck, passing `i` by reference is slower that `i+=2` (as is calling a function)

Comment: @Frank: we all seem to be in agreement that you are trying to optimize the most optimal part of the sample code it presented us.  If you showed us a more real-world example of what you want to do, perhaps we can help there.

Comment: @James Curran, I made my comment before he mentioned he was using a function pointer, so I was thinking the function would be inlined which would remove the overhead of using a reference or using a function.

Comment: Write the code that is easiest to read and maintain first, then measure. If you find performance problems _though measuring_, locate the areas with the most impact on performance first, then implement what you think are improvements there, _then measure again_, to see if your guesses were right.

Comment: @James: There you go. I am used to giving simple examples, but since most of you are experts here, I'll try to give more background in the future...

Comment: “We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.A good programmer will not be lulled into complacency by such reasoning, he will be wise to look carefully at the critical code; but only after that code has been identified” - Donald Kunth -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> "A temporary variable would marginally decrease efficiency, right?"

Wrong.

Have you measured it?  Please be aware that `++` only has magical efficiency powers on a PDP-11.  On most other processors it's just the same as `+=1`.  Please measure the two to see what the actual differences actually are.

Comment: On a PDP-11, compiler optimisations are performed by humans ;)

Comment: OK, I'm intrigued - what magic does a PDP-11 wield that means i++ is faster than i+=1? Some sort of on-chip incrementer instruction similar to INX/INY on the 6502, that the compiler knows about and uses in preference to a standard ALU addition?

Comment: The PDP11's architecture (and many that have come since) could dereference and increment or decrement a pointer in one instruction.  Often, the increment/decrement is forced to be the data size being loaded/stored (e.g. 1 if loading/storing a byte, 2 if a 16-bit word, etc.)  Different processors support different combinations of pre- and post-increment/decrement.  I know of no architecture that directly favors post-increment for anything other than pointer dereferencing, though some highly-pipelined processors might benefit from post-increment in some cases.

Comment: @Matt Joiner: Not compilers, just optimizers.  Using pre-increment and post-increment `++` is purely a performance optimization tweak for things like I/O drivers and kernel data structure updates and the like.  If they were too slow.

Comment: On an old Z80 chip, add was slower than inc :)

Comment: The 6502 INC instruction is slower than ADC (aside from ADC [$nn,X]). However, whereas INC operates directly on memory, ADC operates on the Accumulator - thus the fastest ADC 'Add +1 to Memory' is actually LDA $memory / CLC / ADC #1 / STA $memory - which is 10 cycles, compared to INC $memory, which is 5, 6 or 7 cycles depending on addressing mode.

So for a 6502 compiler (hah!) the pre/postfix operator ++i / i++ would be slower than i+=1 if it tried to 'optimise' using the INC instruction. :)

Answer (score 18):

> (A temporary variable would marginally decrease efficiency, right?)

If that's the main reason you're asking, then you're worrying far too early. Don't second-guess your compiler until you have an actual performance problem.

If you want fkt to be able to add different amounts to i, then you need to pass a parameter. There is no material reason to prefer `++` over `+=`.

Comment: +1: "Don't second-guess your compiler". A good motto for life.

Answer (score 9):

You could increment twice, then subtract, something like:

```
return (i += 2) - 2
```

Just answering the question, though, I don't think you should be scared of using a temporary variable.

Comment: Best answer for the actual question.  I agree with you and the other answers that the temporary would be better.

Comment: As far as efficiency goes, compiling with gcc 4.4.1 -O2 produces the exact same assembly as using a temporary.

Answer (score 4):

If you really need that speed, then check the assembly code the compiler outputs. If you do:

```
int t = i;
i+=2;
return t;
```

then the compiler may optimize it while inlining the function into something like:

```
printf("%d ", i);
i+=2;
```

Which is as good as it's gonna get.

EDIT: Now you say you're jumping to this function via a function pointer? Calling a function by a pointer is pretty slow compared to using a temporary variable. I'm not certain, but I think I remember the Intel docs saying it's somewhere around 20-30 cpu cycles on Core 2s and i7s, that is if your function code is all in cache. Since the compiler cannot inline your function when it is called by a pointer, the ++ will also create a temporary variable anyways.

Answer (score 3):

> A temporary variable would marginally
>   decrease efficiency, right?

Always take in account "premature optimization is the root of all evil". Spend time on other parts then try to optimize this away. += and ++ will probably result in the same thing. Your PC will manage ;)

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could do

```
return i+=2, i-2;
```

That said, just follow this simple maxim:

> Write code that is easy to understand.

Code that is easy for a human to understand is usually easy for the compiler to understand and hence the compiler can optimise it.

Writing crazy stuff in an effort to optimise your code often just confuses the compiler and makes it harder for the compiler to optimise your code.

I would recommend

```
int fkt(int &i)
{
    int orig = i;
    i += 2;
    return orig;
}
```

Comment: The difference in the assembley for these two should be insignificant and the second one is much nicer to read.

Comment: +1 for the simple maxim, "Write code that is easy to understand."

Comment: The second example only works in C++ (or at least GCC throws `error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token`). Is there an equivalent as nice as this that works in standard C?

Answer (score 2):

A "temporary variable" will very unlikely decrease performance, as i++ has to hold the old state internally to (i.e. it implicitly uses what you call a temprorary variable). However, the instruction that is needed to increase by two may be slower than the one used for ++.

You can try:

```
int fkt(int &i)
{
  ++ii;
  return i++;
}
```

You can compare this to:

```
int fkt(int &i)
{
  int t = i;
  i += 2;
  return t;
}
```

That said, I don't think you should be doing any such performance considerations prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want is a functor:

```
class Fkt
{
   int num;
public:
   Fkt(int i) :num(i-2) {}
   operator()() { num+=2; return num; }
}

int main() 
{ 
  Fkt fkt(5); 
  printf("%d ", fkt()); 
  printf("%d ", fkt()); 
  printf("%d ", fkt()); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What about

```
int a = 0;
++++a;
```

Increments +2 without temporary variables.

EDIT:
Oops, sorry: didn't notice you want to achieve 5,7,9. This requires temporary variables so prefix notation can't be used.

Comment: `++++a;` is illegal.  You cannot modify a variable twice between sequence points.

Comment: Does it mean I shall get a compile error? Because I don't.
Anyway, I don't see why is illegal to do ++(++i). It seems perfectly legal to me to increase a variable before increase it again.

But yo got the exp, so I guess I'm wrong anyway. Waiting for clarification :)

Comment: Ok, I think I got it: I thought that prefix increment defined a sequence point, but seems not. So, ++a + ++b is illegal, too? As I read that + operator doesn't define one either.

Comment: Sorry, I meant ++a + ++a :) obviously the former wouldn't change the same variable twice.

Comment: `++++a;` is illegal even *without* considering sequence points; `++` only applies to lvalues, and the result of `++a` is not an lvalue.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong and misread it, but in 5.3.2 [expr.pre.incr] it says "The operand of prefix ++ is modified by adding 1, or set to true if it is bool (this use is deprecated). The operand shall be a modifiable lvalue. The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic type or a pointer to a completely-defined object type. The value is the new value of the operand; it is an lvalue."

While in postfix is says "the result is an rvalue".